# loading images from firebase to uitableviewcell

Tags: swift, image, firebase, caching

I am trying to create a UITableView that will load posts and pictures from firebase. The posts load fine, but the images, only the most bottom cell shows the image while the other cells load the image only after I perform tableView.reloadData(). I would like to have all the images loaded properly into each cell when the user opens UITableView.

I am also using a cache method so the user only has to download the images once. Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Here is the cache method I have been trying:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
var imageUrlString: String?

extension UIImageView {



func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {

    imageUrlString = urlString

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

  image = UIImage(named: "addpic")

    if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as 
AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        self.image = imageFromCache
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler: { 
(data, respones, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)

            if imageUrlString == urlString {
                self.image = imageToCache
            }

            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as 
AnyObject) 
tableView.reloadData() 
        })

    }).resume()
}

}
```

In my UITableViewCell swift file I hook up the UIImage:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var posterProfilePic: UIImageView!
```

In order to load the image from firebase/cache I call the cache method:

```
    func getShoutoutPic() {
    if let profileImageUrl = shoutout?.picsImageUrl {
    self.posterProfilePic.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: 
    profileImageUrl) }

    }
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: I think I found the answer in someone else's post but basically in ViewDidLoad I added:  
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2){
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

Comment: You should put the code to reload the `UITableView` in the completion handler rather than calling it after two seconds. This ensures that the table view is updated once the images were loaded.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm quite unfamiliar with completion handler. Do I just put the tableView.reloadData at the end of the DispatchQueue as listed above?